# Wordpress table plugin floats elements below it

Tags: wordpress

Good day

I am using the easy table plugin (http://wordpress.org/support/view/plugin-reviews/easy-table) and I have a problem with floats with it: Any content I add below the table floats to the right of the table...

Now I can solve this by using a

```
<div style="clear: both"></div>
```

but isn't there a more 'user-friendly' way of doing it? That way my clients(with no html/css experience) can use the tables without problems...

Table Shortcode Code:

```
[table caption="Just test table" width="500" colwidth="20|100|50" colalign="left|left|center|left|right"]
no,head1,head2,head3,head4
1,row1col1,row1col2,row1col3,100
2,row2col1,row2col2,row2col3,20000
3,row3col1,,row3col3,1405
4,row4col1,row4col2,row4col3,23023
[/table]
```

Any suggestions?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the CSS the table uses. Right now it probably uses `float:left` values.

Use Firebug or a similar tool to check if this is the case, and try to edit the CSS.